# jQuery 1.8.0-min Syntax error, unrecognized expression

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I've got a jQuery star rating that works perfectly with jQuery 1.7.2 but returns a syntax error when using jQuery 1.8.0.  Here's the script:

```
/* ====== STAR RATING ========= */
    jQuery(".stars.active a.star").hover(
        function(){
            var elemID = jQuery(this).parent('.stars').attr('id');
            elemID = elemID.replace('id-', '');

            if (od_readCookie('voted-'+elemID) == 'TRUE') {
                jQuery(this).siblings('.ty').html('You already voted.');
            } else {    

                var theClass = jQuery(this).attr('class');
                theClass = theClass.match(/^s[0-9]/);
                var starNum = theClass[0].replace('s', '');
                var allClasses = '';
                for(i=1;i<=starNum;i++) {
                    allClasses += ' .s'+i+', ';
                }
                jQuery(this).parent('.stars').children('.star').addClass('nogold');         
                jQuery(this).parent('.stars').children(allClasses).addClass('hover');
            }
        },
        function(){
            var elemID = jQuery(this).parent('.stars').attr('id');
            elemID = elemID.replace('id-', '');

            if (od_readCookie('voted-'+elemID) == 'TRUE') {
                jQuery(this).siblings('.ty').html('');
            } else {            
                jQuery(this).parent('.stars').children('.star').removeClass('nogold');                  
                jQuery(this).parent('.stars').children('.star').removeClass('hover');
            }
        }
    );

    // actually add the rating
    jQuery(".stars.active a.star").click(function(){
        var elemID = jQuery(this).parent('.stars').attr('id');
        elemID = elemID.replace('id-', ''); 

        if (od_readCookie('voted-'+elemID) != 'TRUE') {

            var theClass = jQuery(this).attr('class');
            theClass = theClass.match(/^s[0-9]/);
            var starNum = theClass[0].replace('s', '');


            // keep the marking while rating updating
            var allClasses = '';
            for(i=1;i<=starNum;i++) {
                allClasses += ' .s'+i+', ';
            }
            jQuery(this).parent('.stars').children('.star').addClass('nogold_voted');           
            jQuery(this).parent('.stars').children(allClasses).addClass('hover_voted');

            jQuery(this).siblings('.ty').load('/od/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=od_add_vote&id='+elemID+'&rating='+starNum);
        }

    });
```

I'm not affluent with jQuery, so can anyone shed a bit of light and what exactly is causing the problem?

Comment: What is the error message? Which line does it occur at? Your console usually tells you these things.

Comment: How about posting the error you get from your console ?

Comment: what is exactly the error reported from your console?

Comment: Which line is the syntax error?

Comment: There's no error message in your question, even you javascript is incomplete, how are we supposed to answer it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I think I found it. This code is causing problems:

```
var allClasses = '';
for(i=1;i<=starNum;i++) {
   allClasses += ' .s'+i+', ';
}
jQuery(this).parent('.stars').children('.star').addClass('nogold');         
jQuery(this).parent('.stars').children(allClasses).addClass('hover');
```

And this

```
var allClasses = '';
for(i=1;i<=starNum;i++) {
    allClasses += ' .s'+i+', ';
}
jQuery(this).parent('.stars').children('.star').addClass('nogold_voted');           
jQuery(this).parent('.stars').children(allClasses).addClass('hover_voted');
```

In both cases `allClasses` variable ends with a comma at the end, so the final selector is something like `.s0.s1,.s2,s3,s4,` what is acceptable in jQuery 1.7, but doesn't work in 1.8+.

So the solution is to remove last comma from the variable: `allClasses = allClasses.slice(0, -1)` after each loop.

So you should end up with something like this:

```
var allClasses = '';
for(i=1;i<=starNum;i++) {
   allClasses += ' .s'+i+', ';
}
allClasses = allClasses.slice(0, -1);

jQuery(this).parent('.stars').children('.star').addClass('nogold');         
jQuery(this).parent('.stars').children(allClasses).addClass('hover');
```

AND

```
var allClasses = '';
for(i=1;i<=starNum;i++) {
    allClasses += ' .s'+i+', ';
}
allClasses = allClasses.slice(0, -1);

jQuery(this).parent('.stars').children('.star').addClass('nogold_voted');           
jQuery(this).parent('.stars').children(allClasses).addClass('hover_voted');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your code and avoid the selector problem by adding a *s* class to all you stars elements.

Then it will be easy to select all :

```
 // keep the marking while rating updating
 jQuery(this).parent('.stars').children('.star').addClass('nogold_voted');           
 jQuery(this).parent('.stars').children('.s').addClass('hover_voted');
```